# Скрипт на несколько заданий

Tags: кластер, java, shell

Для работы на кластере нужно запустить несколько одноузловых заданий с разными параметрами.
Сама программа написана на java.   
Вот пример скрипта, который запускает 1 экземпляр программы на 1 узле(12 ядер):

> **#!/bin/sh** 
> **#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=12**  
> **java -cp /home/mk/joda-time-2.2.jar:/home/mk/Grid.jar** **Service.Grid 10 0 0 0 10**

*PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=12* (1 узел, 12 ядер)   
*java -cp /home/mk/joda-time-2.2.jar* (сторонняя библиотека)  
*/home/mk/Grid.jar Service.Grid* (путь до jar-ника и исполняемый класс)   
*10 0 0 0 10* (параметры, передаваемые программе)

Как переделать его так, чтобы он запускал несколько заданий?

**UPDATE**
Для теста сделал вот такой скрипт:

> **#!/bin/sh** 
> **#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1**  
> **#PBS -d .**
>
> **declare -a PARAMSETS= ("5 0 0 0 2", "5 0 0 2 4")**
>
> **java -cp /home/mk/joda-time-2.2.jar:/home/mk/GridDSP5.jar Service.Grid ${PARAMSETS[$PBS_ARRAYID]}**

Вот команда на выполнение:

> qsub -t 0-1 Grid_test.sh

В итоге, вроде бы, запустилось 2 задания, только оба завершились с ошибками:

> /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/104488-0.hadoop2-00.yandex.ru.SC:
> line 5: syntax error near unexpected
> token `('
> /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/104488-0.hadoop2-00.yandex.ru.SC:
> line 5:`declare -a PARAMSETS= ("5 0 0
> 0 2", "5 0 0 2 4")'

Чет не пойму, с чем тут косяк..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, вот такой скрипт привел к долгожданному решению:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -d .

declare -a PARAMSETS=("5 0 0 0 2" "5 0 0 2 4")

java -cp /home/mk/joda-time-2.2.jar:/home/mk/Grid.jar Service.Grid         ${PARAMSETS[$PBS_ARRAYID]}
```

Команда на запуск:

> Цитата qsub -t 0-1 Grid_test.sh

Интересным является то, что набор параметров не нужно отделять запятой, хотя, как мне казалось, это должно быть интуитивно понятно..